# Let (X,T ) be a topological space. Suppose U ⊆ X, V ⊆ X

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove on topological space

a). Let (X,T ) be a topological space. Suppose U ⊆ X, V ⊆ X, and U ∩ V= ∅. Then Cl(U) ∩ Cl(V) = ∅.

b). Let (X,T ) be a topological space. Suppose U ⊆ X, V ⊆ X, and U ∩ V≠∅. Then Cl(U) ∩ Cl(V) ≠ ∅.

where Cl is closure of subset

Comment: It sounds fine to me.

Comment: It's correct .For (b) you can also note that $A\subset Cl(A)$ for any $A,$ so $Cl(U)\cap Cl(V)\supset U\cap Cl(V)\supset U\cap V.$

Answer (score 0):

a) is quite correct: a more extreme counterexample : $U =\mathbb{Q} ,V = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, usual topology of the reals; both of them are dense, so $\operatorname{Cl}(U) = \operatorname{V} = \mathbb{R}$, while $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Your example is fine as well.

b) is also OK, indeed:

$$\emptyset \neq U \cap V \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(U) \cap \operatorname{Cl}(V)$$ from $A \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ for any subset $A$.